# Получение id статей отфильтрованных по дате из нескольких инфоблоков в Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Добрый день,

Не могу никак решить задачу с получением id статей отфильтрованных по дате из нескольких инфоблоков.

В принципе задача тривиальная и реализована на многих сайта, когда на главную нужно вывести последние сообщения из всех разделов в порядке 
даты их публикации, но я не представляю как это сделать на bitrix.

Приведу пример того что я хочу реализовать:

Есть 5 инфоблоков с $iblock_id 24,31,45,55,67

В 1-ом инфоблоке с $iblock_id 24 последняя статья написана 9 января ее id 127 
В 2-ом инфоблоке с $iblock_id 31 последняя статья написана 6 января ее id 111 
В 3-ом инфоблоке с $iblock_id 45 последняя статья написана 1 января ее id 84 
В 4-ом инфоблоке с $iblock_id 55 последняя статья написана 4 января ее id 105 
В 5-ом инфоблоке с $iblock_id 67 последняя статья написана 3 января ее id 97

Нужно получить id статей из перечисленных инфоблоков в порядке убывания даты написания.

Т.е.

1. id статьи написанной 9 января (из примера id 127)
2. id статьи написанной 6 января (из примера id 111)
3. id статьи написанной 4 января (из примера id 105)
4. id статьи написанной 3 января (из примера id 97)
5. id статьи написанной 1 января (из примера id 84)

В примере указано 5 инфоблоков, реально их намного больше и количество будет расти.

Я думаю, что логика должна быть следущая: 
Находим последнюю опубликованную статью в каждом из заданных по $iblock_id инфоблоков и вытаскиваем ее id и дату. 
Создаем массив.

Дальше отфильтровываем массив по дате в порядке убывания.

Получаем последние N элементов массива с датами и id.

Как вытащить id последней статьи из заданного инфоблока я разобрался

```html
<? 
if (CModule::IncludeModule("iblock")): 

$iblock_id = 15; 
$i = 0; 

$my_elements = CIBlockElement::GetList ( 
Array("ID" => "desc"), 
Array("IBLOCK_ID" => $iblock_id), 
false, 
Array ("nTopCount" => 1), 
Array('ID') 
); 

while($ar_fields = $my_elements->GetNext()) 
{ 
if($i == 0) $id1=$ar_fields; 
} 
endif; 
?>
```

, но как реализовать фильтр с массивом не могу понять.

Спасибо за внимание. Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Ну ты можешь это сделать не через API а вот так, только добавь условие в подзапрос из каких инфоблоков тянуть WHERE IBLOCK_ID in ()

```
GLOBAL $DB;
$res = $DB->query(
    'SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT ID,NAME,DATE_CREATE,PREVIEW_TEXT,PREVIEW_PICTURE,IBLOCK_ID
        FROM b_iblock_element
        ORDER BY DATE_CREATE DESC
    ) as t  
    GROUP BY IBLOCK_ID
    ORDER BY DATE_CREATE DESC
');

while($row = $res->Fetch()) {
    //тут обработай там картинки вытащи или свойства если нужны
}
```